# Get current post's category

Tags: django

So as the title says, i need to get the current post's category to use it in a "related posts" section, more precisely what to put in `cat_posts = Post.objects.filter(Category=????)`
(don't mind the comments variable since i removed part of my PostView from this post)

here's my code

views.py

```
def PostView(request, slug):
template_name = 'post-page.html'
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

cat_posts = Post.objects.filter(Category=Post.Category)
cat_posts = cat_posts.order_by('-Date')[:3}

return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                       'cat_posts':cat_posts})
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)



class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
Category = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='None')
Thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
Text = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Overview = models.CharField(max_length=400)
Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
main_story = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.title)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    # return reverse('about', args=(str(self.id)))
    return reverse('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this with the `post.Category` (so the `post` *object, not the <s>`Post`</s> class):

```
def PostView(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post-page.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    cat_posts = Post.objects.filter(
        Category=post.Category
    ).order_by('-Date')[:3]
    return render(
        request,
        template_name,
        {'post': post, 'cat_posts':cat_posts}
    )
```

It is however better to work with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to the `Category` than a `CharField`: if you later change the name of the category, then your posts are no longer pointing to a valid category.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `category` instead of <s>`Category`</s>.

Comment: thank you. that worked, i had tried it already with the Post class not the post object. as for changing category to ForeignKey, what should i put in "on_delete" ?

Comment: @adelbouakaz: the question is, what should happen to the posts if you delete a category. See the documentation for possible scenarios: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: ok thanks, i didn't know SET_DEFAULT exisited